# How to create .mpp file in java?

Tags: java, ms-project, mpxj

I am able to create .**mpx** file by using ***mpxj*** library in java.
    I need write ( create ) .**mpp** file in java can any one suggest me ***please***.

Comment: Hi Alex,  I have tried to create Microsoft Project (MPP) file in java.        I am able read it by mpxj library but unable to write it. Please suggest if it is possible to create mpp file in java ?

Comment: You can read this [topic of faq](http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/faq.html#write-mpp).

Comment: faq is now here: http://www.mpxj.org/faq/

Answer (score 8):

I maintain MPXJ, and the short answer to your enquiry is that, at present, MPXJ does not write MPP files.

The main reason for this is simply that despite the effort which has gone into understanding the MPP file structure, there is still a great deal of it which is not well understood, hence it is difficult to reliably generate. The other issue is that even if I was to produce some code which could generate an MPP file, the features it could write to that file are likely to lag behind what MPXJ supports in the MSPDI file format, again due to my incomplete understanding of the MPP format.

My suspicion is that the next version of MS project (project 15? Project 2013?) may probably offer a ".mppx" file format, similar to the ".docx" etc formats used by other applications in the MS Office suite. This will be XML-based and will be more straightforward to generate than the binary MPP file format currently is... let's see what Microsoft come up with!

Jon

Comment: is that true that MPP is a database like MSAccess?

Comment: No, it's an OLE compound document... in effect it's a file system which contains a number of individual files representing different parts of the project plan (tasks, resources, calendars, and so on). I've seen no evidence to suggest that it's a database though. I think the files are just serialised C or C++ structs.

Answer (score 1):

Visit http://www.mpxj.org/faq/
Can I use MPXJ to write MPP files?

```
Not at present. Although it is technically feasible to generate an MPP   file, the knowledge we have of the file structure is still relatively   incomplete, despite the amount of data we are able to correctly extract. It   is therefore likely to take a considerable amount of development effort   to make this work, and it is conceivable that we will not be ablet  to write   the full set of attributes that MPXJ supports back into the MPP  file - simply because we don't understand the format well enough. You are  therefore probably better off using MSPDI which does support the full range  of data items present in an MPP file.
```

You can

Try this: http://www.aspose.com/java/project-management-component.aspx

It writes MPP and Microsoft Project XML.

**But this not free**

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://www.aspose.com/java/project-management-component.aspx

It writes MPP and Microsoft Project XML.

Answer (score -3):

I think by "mpp" you probably mean "Microsoft PowerPoint", correct?

Q: Why do you think MPXJ (Microsoft Project Exchange/Java) can't do this?

> http://www.mpxj.org/
>
> Welcome to MPXJ! This library provides a set of facilities to allow
> project information to be manipulated in Java and .Net. MPXJ supports
> a range of data formats: Microsoft Project Exchange (MPX), Microsoft
> Project (MPP,MPT), Microsoft Project Data Interchange (MSPDI XML),
> Microsoft Project Database (MPD), Planner (XML), Primavera (PM XML,
> XER, and database), and Asta Powerproject (PP, MDB).

Comment: [link] http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/   But it gave "MPXJ supports read only access to MPP files produced by Microsoft Project 98"  and i have tried to generate mpp by mpxj. but i couldn't. net.sf.mpxj.mpp.MPPReader;  net.sf.mpxj.mpx.MPXWriter; are available in lib but net.sf.mpxj.mpp.MPPWriter; is not available.  any alternate way to create Microsoft Project (MPP) file ?